# Stop wordpress redirecting www to non-www

Tags: redirect

I am just transferring over a WordPress site from Server 1 to Server 2.
The IP address of Server 1 points to `example.com`  (A record on DNS server)
The IP address of Server 2 points to `www.example.com`  (A record on DNS server)

During the migration, I want to type in `www.example.com` and prevent any redirection - so that I can make sure that it has been set up correctly before
setting the A record for `example.com` to point to Server 2.

There is a `.htaccess` file on Server 2, but it isn't redirecting to `example.com`.  Just to make sure that it isn't, I renamed it to `htaccess.bk` to make sure it doesn't kick in - but no success here.

Any idea what I need to do?

TIA!

Comment: Can you share your htaccess code here.

Answer (score 1):

What do you have set in the WordPress admin under Settings -> General and then `WordPress Address` and `Site Address`? Make sure these are both using the `www.example.com` domain.

If you want to use an `htaccess` rule, which will run before WordPress kicks in, there are plenty of answers on StakOverflow such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916222/htaccess-how-to-force-www-in-a-generic-way

Answer (score 1):

Just put this code in your `wp-config.php` file

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'your_url' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'your_url' );
```

In .htaccess file:

## Force www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

## Force non-www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** You need just comment out these two lines in .htaccess file by using `#` just putting before the line

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Please explain why do you think it will be helpful...

Comment: Actually, home_url and site_url exist in the wp_options table so first WordPress checks in that table. We can override it from config file also.

Comment: I know, but... If you want your answer to be helpful, then always explain such solutions, so anyone reading it may understand how does it work ;)

Comment: These settings are useful when working on a local or staging server so that you don't have to keep changing the database wp_options. We run a WordPress composer setup with a local-wp-config file include with settings specific to the server environment. In the OP's case, they should just edit the URLs via the admin.